# Unable to paste text from Illustrator into Wygwam field

Tags: wygwam

I am working on a site from designs done in Illustrator and when I try and copy text from the Illustrator document and paste it into Wygwam nothing happens. It is just blank. I have to first paste the copy into a text editor and then copy it and paste it into Wygwam for it to work. Does anyone else have this problem and is there a solution?

Comment: Can't really answer the question, but... Did you try using Wygwam's "Paste as Plain Text" button? If that doesn't help then one faster alternative to using the intermediary text file is to use [Plain Clip](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/plain-clip/)

Comment: ditto what @Alex Kendrick said. Sometimes you just have to convert to text before pasting into the "Paste as Plain Text" area as well.

Comment: Are you copying the text content of a "box" or the box itself? But...avoid paste text directly from Illustrator. It's likely to contain line breaks and odd control characters. If you can, paste the text into a code/text editor first then, after cleaning it up, copy/paste that into the Wygwam field.

Comment: I am trying to paste the actual text. As noted in my question I have had to paste into a text editor first and then paste into Wigwam. The Past as Plain Text option does not work.